In ionic 5 keyboard pushes header to upwards only in ios but not in android
This is happening because of up down arrow keys appears when click on text field. Any suggestions how to fix this.
This should not push the header upwards.
Tried with adding the custom CSS to fix the header still it doesn't work out.

is there any absolute positioning in the styles? maybe set all 4 sides instead of just 1?
